# Python Django Multiple Database for User Groups

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Is it possible to use different databases for different user groups without defining database in settings.py ? For example, user group 'X' uses 'A' database and user group 'Y' uses 'B' database in the same app ?

All the best,
Semih

Comment: Yes, it is possible to specify diffrent database for diffrent Group or User use [.using()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases)

Comment: how ? can you describe it a bit more ?